# Set text limit using jquery

Tags: jquery

There is some text comprised of 165 characters. I need to show only the first 155 characters, but the last 5 out of the 155 chars should be replaced with "....." (elipses), and the remaining characters should be removed. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMEju/)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var txt= $('div').text();
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            alert(txt.charAt(150+ i))
        }
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100px">
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Come on @TecHunter, he has a fiddle with things he trying. You have to start learning from somewhere. A -1 on a question with an included fiddle that shows he is trying to learn should get you a -1 yourself. Did you know string functions from day 1?

Comment: @JClaspill okay okay... you are right about question format

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the [substring function here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), and voilà:

```
var txt= $('#restrict').text();
if(txt.length > 155)
    $('#result').text(txt.substring(0,150) + '.....');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/GRmY2/

Comment: You could remove the rude comment and this would get an upvote.

Comment: okay sorry, you are right, I've seen worse questions that's true. I even upvoted your comment as self punishement for being too harsh for this late afternoon :P

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what browsers you're targeting, you could just use css.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

Comment: nice but too specific imo :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like TecHunter already posted pretty much the same thing, but I was bored and did this.

At 155 chars replaces last 5 characters with "....". Has a textarea input with a character counter that updates as you type.

**Html**

```
<div>
    <h2>Input</h2>
    <textarea id="sampleInput">
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.     The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    </textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Character Count:</label> <span id ="charCounter"></span>
<div>
<h2>Output</h2>
<p style="width:100px" id="sampleOutput"></p>
```

**JS**

```
updateOutput();

$('#sampleInput').keyup(function(e){
   updateOutput();
});

function updateOutput(){
    var sampleInput = $('#sampleInput').val(),
        sampleInputLength = sampleInput.length;

    if(sampleInputLength >= 155) {    
        sampleInput = sampleInput.substr(0,150) + ".....";    
    }

    $('#charCounter').text(sampleInputLength);
    $('#sampleOutput').text(sampleInput);
}
```

**CSS**

```
#sampleInput {
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;    
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMEju/5/)**

Comment: I +1 for the effort :) and because you are bored

Comment: @TecHunter If I was really bored, I'd turn this into a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I saw some nice answers, however, some of them are not efficient in other cases, ex: when you copy and paste something.
So, I would suggest:

```
 $(document).on('keyup keypress blur change', '#elementId', function () {
     var maxLength = 100; // number of characters to limit
     imposeMaxLength($(this), maxLength);
 });

 function imposeMaxLength(element, maxLength) {
     if (element.val().length > maxLength) {
         element.val(element.val().substring(0, maxLength));
     }
 }
```

Using imposeMaxLength as function, you can reuse it in other events.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn-custom").text(function(index, currentText) {
    if(currentText.length > 60){
        return currentText.substr(0, 20)+" ...";
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add little briefly about the code you written